# Installed API version 28 (Pie) is not showing in Target Android Version in visual studio 2013

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hi i am using visual studio 2013 and have Xamarin installed in it.

I have updated the Xamarin Tools from Android SDK Manager. API 28 is installed but it is not showing in the Dropdown for selecting the Target Android Version.

I'm not sure of the reason for this. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It is highly recommended to use Visual Studio 2017 to stay on the latest updates of Xamarin.Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin.Android support for Android **P**ie (API Level 28) is currently in preview and is available via VS 2017 15.8 (Preview) and VS4M 7.6.0.xxxx (Preview).

> Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8 – Visual Studio Preview Installer
>
> Visual Studio 2017 for Mac – Beta updater channel

#### Release History for Pie/28 support:

- Xamarin.Android 9.0.0.17 - (Visual Studio 15.8 Preview 5, July 24th, 2018)
- Xamarin.Android 9.0.0.0 - (Visual Studio 15.8 Preview 4, July 10th, 2018)
- Xamarin.Android 8.4.0.1 - (Visual Studio 15.8 Preview 3, June 26th, 2018)
- Xamarin.Android 8.3.99.12 - (Visual Studio 15.8 Preview 2, May 31st, 2018)

> Xamarin.Android 9.0.0 includes preview bindings for Android API-28, bound available as a $(TargetFrameworkVersion) value of v9.0.  The next release -- Visual Studio 15.8 Preview 5 -- will contain final bindings for API-28.

re: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_9/